# Magento 2 Message Queue - Type Error with expected string, null given

Tags: php, xml, magento2

I struggle for 3 days now to get a simple Message Queue in Magento 2 to work. Here are my XML files:

**communication.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Communication/etc/communication.xsd">
    <topic name="erp.queue.order"
           request="string">
        <handler name="erp.queue.order"
                 type="TimoG\OrderTransfer\Model\Queue\Consumer"
                 method="process" />
    </topic>
</config>
```

**queue_consumer.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/consumer.xsd">
    <consumer name="erp.queue.order"
              queue="erp.queue.order"
              connection="db"
              handler="TimoG\OrderTransfer\Model\Queue\Consumer::process"/>
</config>
```

**queue_publisher.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/publisher.xsd">
    <publisher topic="erp.queue.order">
        <connection name="db"
                    exchange="magento-db"
                    disabled="false"/>
    </publisher>
</config>
```

**queue_topology.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/topology.xsd">
    <exchange name="magento-db"
              type="topic"
              connection="db">
        <binding id="TimoGErpOrderTransfer"
                 topic="erp.queue.order"
                 destinationType="queue"
                 destination="erp.queue.order"/>
    </exchange>
</config>
```

So adding messages to the queue works (I see it in the database table "queue_message"), however when I execute `php bin/magento queue:consumers:start erp.queue.order` I always get the following exception:

```
Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Consumer\Config\Data, Argume
  nt 2 passed to Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor::resolveFullyQualifiedClassName() must be o
  f the type string, null given, called in /Users/timog/Sites/magento2.local/vendor/magento/fra
  mework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php on line 545
```

My consumer test code:

```
<?php

namespace TimoG\OrderTransfer\Model\Queue;

use Exception;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

class Consumer
{

    private $_logger;
    private Json $_json;


    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        Json $json
    )
    {
        $this->_json = $json;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }


    public function process($request)
    {
        try {
            $test = $this->_json->unserialize($request);
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            $this->_logger->critical($exc->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what's wrong and I really need help please... it's frustrating...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, after more than 3 months, you already solved your problem, but you just needed to set a type for the `$request` parameter, or to write the PHP Docblock (the comment with `@param` and `@return`) before the `process` function in your consumer's class.

Magento 2, most of the time, uses reflections to validate the type of parameters and returns, taking advantage of the comment before each method/property to retrieve the actual data type.

So basically you should just change your method declaration to this:

```
/**
 * @param string $request
 * @return void
 */
public function process($request)
```

or this:

```
public function process(string $request): void
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you created a custom module with `module.xml` and `registration.xml` files as required in the [official documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/)?

Have you run the `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `bin/magento cache:flush` commands to make sure that the module is properly installed and the database entries are not cached?

Are you working with PHPStorm? You can run `bin/magento dev:urn:generate .idea/misc.xml` to add XSL schema to your IDE config so that it can highlight XML syntax, very useful for XML configuration files.

EDIT: URN schema generation for XML verification.

Comment: Yes I did. I am not new to Magento2 development, it's just I have never worked with Message Queues